# Parse String to Integer

Tags: javascript

I have a string variable, for example:

`var value = "109.90"`

I need to pass this variable as an **integer** to webservice in this format: `10990`

I tried parsing it to integer with `parseInt(value)` but I got `109`
And with `parseFloat(value)` I got `109.9`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You've already figured out how to turn it into a number. You just need to look up how to remove the `.` :)

Comment: Try `value.replace('.','')`

Comment: I can turn it a float, but if I remove the dot it doesn't give me the last 0 that I need

Comment: parseInt(value.replace('.',''))

Comment: Are you confident that your input data will always have exactly two characters after the period?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as in the other answers, but more readable code.

```js
var value = "109.90";

// Replace the decimal point with an empty string
var valueWithoutDecimalPoint = String(value).replace(".", "");

// Parse an integer with the radix value
// This will tell parseInt to use 10-based decimal numbers
// Otherwise you will get weird bugs if your string starts with a 0
var result = parseInt(valueWithoutDecimalPoint, 10);

// It will be NaN if int cannot be parsed
isNaN(result) ? console.error("result is NaN!") : console.log(result); // 10990
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
var value = "109.90";
let result = parseInt(`${value.split(".")[0]}${value.split(".")[1]}`);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I wonder why all the pluses. Solution works, but it is far from optimal.

Comment: This is not very readable code, although it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is probably nicer than my other answer:

```
var result = value * 100
```

Comment: Should you parsefloat on value before you do the multiplication?

Comment: @nixkuroi no, the string is automatically converted to a number

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it's going to fail either way if it's not actually a number coming through, because NaN won't multiply even if you parsed it.  I always like to do the parse ahead of time just to make sure the calculation is going to work.